# Insert elements into a list based on depth and `if` conditions using modify_depth and modify_if (purrr)

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm learning some `purrr` commands, specifically the `modify_*` family of functions. I'm attemping to add `price` bins to items found in a grocery store (see below for my attempt and error code).

```
library(tidyverse)
```

## Data

```
easybuy <- list(
  "5520 N Division St, Spokane, WA 99208, USA",
  list("bananas", "oranges"),
  canned = list("olives", "fish", "jam"),
  list("pork", "beef"),
  list("hammer", "tape")
) %>%
  map(list) %>%
  # name the sublists
  set_names(c("address",
              "fruit",
              "canned",
              "meat",
              "other")) %>%
  # except for address, names the sublists "items"
  modify_at(c(2:5), ~ set_names(.x, "items"))
```

Take a peek:

```
glimpse(easybuy)
#> List of 5
#>  $ address:List of 1
#>   ..$ : chr "5520 N Division St, Spokane, WA 99208, USA"
#>  $ fruit  :List of 1
#>   ..$ items:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "bananas"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "oranges"
#>  $ canned :List of 1
#>   ..$ items:List of 3
#>   .. ..$ : chr "olives"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "fish"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "jam"
#>  $ meat   :List of 1
#>   ..$ items:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "pork"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "beef"
#>  $ other  :List of 1
#>   ..$ items:List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr "hammer"
#>   .. ..$ : chr "tape"
```

## My Attempt

Idea: go in a depth of two, and look for "items", append a "price". I'm not sure if I can nest the `modify` functions like this.

```
easybuy %>% 
  modify_depth(2, ~ modify_at(., "items", ~ append("price")))
#> Error: character indexing requires a named object
```

## Desired

I would like the following structure (**note the addition of "price" under each item**):

```
List of 5
 $ address:List of 1
  ..$ : chr "5520 N Division St, Spokane, WA 99208, USA"
 $ fruit  :List of 1
  ..$ items:List of 2
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "bananas"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "oranges"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
 $ canned :List of 1
  ..$ items:List of 3
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "olives"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "fish"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "jam"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
 $ meat   :List of 1
  ..$ items:List of 2
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "pork"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "beef"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
 $ other  :List of 1
  ..$ items:List of 2
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "hammer"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
  .. ..$ :List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr "tape"
  .. .. ..$ : chr "price"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems working. The `map_if` and `function(x) !is.null(names(x))` make sure the change only happen if the name of the item is not `NULL`. `~modify_depth(.x, 2, function(y) list(y, "price"))` creates the list you need.

```
library(tidyverse)

easybuy2 <- easybuy %>%
  map_if(function(x) !is.null(names(x)),
         ~modify_depth(.x, 2, function(y) list(y, "price")))
```

Here is how the second item looks like.

```
easybuy2[[2]][[1]]
# [[1]]
# [[1]][[1]]
# [1] "bananas"
# 
# [[1]][[2]]
# [1] "price"
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# [[2]][[1]]
# [1] "oranges"
# 
# [[2]][[2]]
# [1] "price"
```

Or this also works.

```
easybuy3 <- easybuy %>% 
  modify_at(2:5, ~modify_depth(.x, 2, function(y) list(y, "price")))

identical(easybuy2, easybuy3)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Update**

```
easybuy4 <- easybuy %>%
  map_if(function(x){
    name <- names(x) 
    if(is.null(name)){
      return(FALSE)
    } else {
      return(name %in% "items")
    }
  },
~modify_depth(.x, 2, function(y) list(y, "price")))

identical(easybuy2, easybuy4)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This solves my problem. Thank you! Follow-up however ... my hope was that I'd be able to ONLY modify at list items containing an "item" sublist. Hence my attempt at modify_if. Is this still possible?